# Is there a flag that indicates that `viewDidAppear` was called?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

Is there a flag that indicates that `viewDidAppear` was called ?

I guess I can create my own flag in subclassed UIViewController but I was wondering if there is something already.

The reason I'm asking is because I want to dismiss the view when some server-side event occurs. The problem is that network event is asynchronous therefore I don't know if view is fully constructed yet. For now I had to add two properties to my controller `viewAppeared` and `errorOccured` and check them in network observer and `videDidLoad` respectively. It looks like boiler-plate code that I'd like to remove because UIKit has to have some internal flag that indicates whether view is fully displayed.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Turned out there [is `int` flag](https://github.com/kennytm/iphone-private-frameworks/blob/master/UIKit/UIViewController2.h#L67) in `UIViewController` that is called `_appearState`. When it's 2 that means view has appeared.

Comment: That's the "private" side of an Apple framework and *could* change or disappear between iOS versions.  So while it works for you now, it might break down the road.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann You're right. But that's ok (in my case). I release software more often than Apple updates iOS :)

Comment: Doesn't matter if you update a lot - it's bad practice and against Apple's guidelines if they find you doing this your new update to the store can be rejected.  Also you have no guarantee that a user will update an app the day you release an update leading to a bad user experience.

Answer (score -1):

The [documentation for "`viewDidAppear`"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidAppear%3a) says:

> Notifies the view controller that its view was added to a view
>   hierarchy.

So another "flag" you can use is to see if the view controller's view has a ["`superview`" property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/superview), which is part of the view hierarchy.

Comment: There also one thing to take in to account, I'm not sure about that, but I think, view controller that's being presented can have "superView" before transition animation is over. So trying to dismiss it would cause an exception.

Comment: Actually I just checked and turned out `superview` is set before `viewDidAppear` is called. So I ended up having two custom flags in my class. I don't like it but I guess I have no choice here.

Comment: I suspect `superview` is nil when "`viewWillAppear`" is called and is set to a valid superview when "`viewDidAppear`" is called.

Comment: Checking for the superview property being non-nil isn't safe. I've just fixed a bug whereby the code was checking superview in this way. Once I replaced that with a flag based on viewDidAppear being called, a horrible bug went away.

Comment: To clarify: I'm saying that I believe there's a window of opportunity between superview being set and viewDidAppear being called whereby it's not safe to assume the view has appeared